# "Scrapy" Installation Error using pip install

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy from the command line and getting the following error.

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\paran\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\paran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sa3_a6ft\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\paran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sa3_a6ft\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\paran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-egqr0bb7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\paran\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\Twisted'
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Please share the command(s) used, as well as some information on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [installation guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) it's recommended to install Scrapy with anaconda or miniconda. Installing scrapy on Windows using pip is a headache.

I installed it right now at my office pc running on windows 10 using pip to test it:

win10, python 3.7

- manually download twisted from
  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- choose the version and download Twisted-18.7.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

> ```
> cd to files download directory
> pip install Twisted-18.7.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl  
> pip install scrapy 
> pip install pypiwin32
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It helped. But pycharm does not seem to recognize it. I am trying to run the script and it gives the following error:  import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'

Comment: What python version do you have installed?

Comment: I think you installed twisted for python2. When you use the command pip , you are installing a package for python2. You are using python3 (3.6.3). To install twisted for python3, you have to do: pip3 install twisted

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.2. I installed Scrapy using Miniconda, however, when I typed Scrapy in cmd line, I get this:The 'Twisted>=17.9.0' distribution was not found and is required by Scrapy

Comment: I've gone through this mess. the wheel file is located on some obscure edu site and is required for windows. Thank goodness I don't develop on windows anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In windows Scrapy required some dependencies before installation please read this 
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

There is also another way to install Scrapy in windows using anaconda

Comment: Thanks. I used Miniconda to install Scrapy. However, I am facing an additional issue while running a script through Pycharm, it is showing that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted' ". How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html?

Comment: I did. It installed perfectly. However, when I looked at Scrapy from cmd line, I got this: The 'Twisted>=17.9.0' distribution was not found and is required by Scrapy